# invoking createDisplay on android.view.SurfaceControl using reflection returns null

Tags: android

I am trying to call `createDisplay` method on `android.view.SurfaceControl` using reflection but it is returning null on Marshmallow device. I Don't know why.

The reason to do is to create virtualdisplay without using MediaProjection API.
Following is the code.

```
Class surfaceControlClass = Class.forName("android.view.SurfaceControl");
Class cls = surfaceControlClass;
IBinder token = (IBinder) cls.getDeclaredMethod("createDisplay", new Class[]{String.class, Boolean.TYPE}).invoke(null, new Object[]{name, Boolean.valueOf(false)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need System Permission(android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER) to do that, check your LogCat and you will find permission warning.
Actually you can't make it work unless you have the Platform Signature of your device.
But you can test it on emulator using the default AOSP signature.

Comment: Thnks for the prompt reply. But when i put it in manifest.xml it says permission for system apps only :( . How can we have platform signature  Or you are saying its not possible without the signature?

Comment: Just to add to it actually i thought i will do what App like vysor does. It does not ask for permission for projecting the display or mirroring . When i decompiled the app and looked into the code i found this route  via reflection. But thet app is installed as normal app on my device.

Comment: You can't get platform signature unless the device is made by you or it flashed debug rom or third-party rom like CM which use google's AOSP signature.

Comment: so is there any other way i can do virtualdisplay for screen recording without asking for permission like mediaprojection api?

Comment: No, you can't. The only way is MediaProjection. If you skip the ask dialog, it means you find a secure vulnerability of Android

Comment: Thnks for your reply.By the way i suppose Vysor utilizes some other hack to do it since it doesnt ask any permission. You too can install and check :). Giving a like for your response.

Comment: I'll check it later. I've wrote system level screen recoder for phone manufacturer many years. edit: I noticed that Vysor use USB and ADB, you know that PC can read phone's screen via ADB without any permission

Comment: Yes.but screenshot via adb is very slow(500-700 ms) for 1 screenshot :(. Also Recording is restricted to 3 min max

Comment: I tried SurfaceControl.createDisplay with system signature, and get Screen successfully. I guess Shell has permission ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER

Comment: SurfaceControl.createDisplay with system signature means system permission as described above by you?